# Why can't you use operators in array values inside a class?

Tags: php, class

Try this:

```
$test = array (2+2);
var_dump($test);
```

Then try the same but inside a class:

```
class test {
    public $test = array(2+2);
}
```

I just want to know why one gets a parser error and maybe how to solve this (in a class) as code-friendly and performant as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use statements to initialize class fields. It must be a literal, a constant value. A workaround is to use a constructor:

```
class Test {
    public $test;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->test = array(2+2);
    }
}
```

From **[the manual:](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)**

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords `public`, `protected`, or `private`,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may
>   include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

Comment: Thanks! Any workaround?  I need this test class as configuration class without too much garble around.

Comment: @R-U-Bn: a constructor is usually better than any initialization. Use it, you only need to do it once.

Comment: "Better" depends on it's use.  I needed an average php-dummy to be able to set these configurations in a configuration file and this way could be not simple enough.  For ref. only, because meanwhile I solved my problem via mysql set-types.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because assignments to properties in a class must be static declarations.  They cannot be expressions that are evaluated.

That is you can do:

```
public $test = array(4); // static assignment
public $test = 'some string'; // static assignment
public $test = strtoupper('  some string  '); // invalid, expression
public $test = $global_variable; // invalid, not a constant expression
public $test = time(); // invalid, an expression
```